# Programmatic equivalent of vmstat or eeheap

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

I'm looking for a way for a C# program to dump an overview of its own memory stats to the console at intervals.

According to:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

WinDbg has a command called `vmstat` and another command called `!eeheap -gc` each of which prints out a nice block of statistics.

It seems to me that this functionality should not be restricted to manual operation, that it should be possible for a program to automatically do something similar in itself without WinDbg. Is there anything in either the standard library or a Nuget package that would do this?

(Not that I am *not* asking for ingredients, ways to get individual numbers that would go into such a summary. I'm aware GC, Process et cetera have many such individual numbers, more than one could ever enumerate or compare. I'm asking for a packaged solution.)

Comment: I think you just answered your own question - it can't be that difficult for you to write a simple method that prints values from the `System.GC` class to stdout - certainly nothing that justifies creating an entire NuGet package dependency for.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd

Comment: @Dai To be sure, printing values is easy; it's figuring out which values to print, and how they relate to each other, that's the hard part.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! That does look useful for processing crash dumps; the FAQ says it doesn't yet handle live processes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there doesn't really seem to be anything prepackaged; the following is the code I came up with.

```
var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
Util.WriteHeading("cpu");
Util.WriteItem("user", process.UserProcessorTime);
Util.WriteItem("system", process.PrivilegedProcessorTime);
Util.WriteItem("total CPU", process.TotalProcessorTime);
Console.WriteLine();

Util.WriteHeading("memory");
Util.WriteItem("private", process.PrivateMemorySize64);
Util.WriteItem("total memory", GC.GetTotalMemory(false));
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i <= GC.MaxGeneration; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
        sb.Append('/');
    sb.Append(GC.CollectionCount(i));
}
Util.WriteItem("collection count", sb.ToString());
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("                          Current             Peak");
Console.WriteLine("{0,16} {1,16:n0} {2,16:n0}",
    "Paged",
    process.PagedMemorySize64,
    process.PeakPagedMemorySize64);
Console.WriteLine("{0,16} {1,16:n0} {2,16:n0}",
    "Working Set",
    process.WorkingSet64,
    process.PeakWorkingSet64);
Console.WriteLine("{0,16} {1,16:n0} {2,16:n0}",
    "Virtual Memory",
    process.VirtualMemorySize64,
    process.PeakVirtualMemorySize64);
Console.WriteLine();

Util.WriteHeading("stopwatch");
Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed);
Console.WriteLine();
```